# WPF Stackpanel visible height

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have a StackPanel, which contains vertically more children than can fit on the visible part of the StackPanel.

I need to know the real visible area's height of the StackPanel - but ActualHeight Property returns the actual size of all the children inside the StackPanel.. How to get the visible size?

Answer (score 1):

DesiredSize.Height - Margin.Top - Margin.Bottom

Answer (score 0):

You could just check the size of the StackPanel's parent.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that the parent is a Grid and this StackPanel is inside one column - the Parent's size returns the whole parent Grid's size

Comment: Then why don't you just check the appropriate row's `ActualHeight` or the column's `ActualWidth`?

Comment: Because I don't want the control to be dependent of the container it is placed on - it could be any container, like Canvas or StackPanel or anything. So I will just choose the solution I found myself which works in every situation: DesiredSize.Height - Margin.Top - Margin.Bottom

Comment: I doubt that it works in "every situation", but go ahead. I'd expect that a StackPanel's `DesiredSize` would always return the *desired* height, i.e. the height it needs to display all children. And the Margin would have to be set somehow by application code. The parent won't do that during layout.